# How to retrieve data stored under different key in Firebase Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an app that allows user to scan a barcode and stores book's information and retrieves them on to a TableView. The books are stored under current user ID -> books -> name of the book -> title, author ..etc. see JSON Structure below:-

[image: JSON Data Structure]

So there are books with different names and every time a new book is scanned, it gets added under 'books'.

How do I get the data of all books under different names?

Here's the code, where I am trying to retrieve the data in TableViewController:

```
var posts = [BooksFromFirebase]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //get reference to data location
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

    //get current user id
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser

   databaseRef.child("users").child((user?.uid)!).child("books").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let value = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
        let assetTitle = value["title"] as? String ?? ""
        print("Title ",assetTitle)
        let title = assetTitle
        let type = "Book"

        self.posts.insert(BooksFromFirebase(title: title, type: type), at: 0)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })     
}
```

Comment: Where is the error? Try  printing `databaseRef.child("users").child((user?.uid)!).child("books")`, do you get the desired path?

Comment: Thanks for replying @Dravidian. Apparently, there isn't any error. The path works fine and I am getting the data. However, if you see my JSON structure, I store books under the title of each book. So I i'm not sure how to call each book to retrieve the data inside them. In this case I have a unique name for each book.

Comment: for example, I can't do: 'databaseRef.child("users").child((user?.uid)!).child("books"‌​).child("BOOK'S NAME")' because the name of the book varies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this :-

```
    Database.database().reference().child("users/(user!.uid)/books").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(Snapshot) in


            if let eachDict = Snapshot.value as? NSDictionary{

                for each in eachDict{

                    print(each.key ?? "No Data")
                    print(each.value ?? "No Data")
                    print((each.value as! NSDictionary)["title"] ?? "No data")

                }
            }

    }, withCancel: {(Err) in

        // Handle error encountered while communicating via firebase

    })
```

Comment: Thank you @Dravidian. None of the print statement works. But I printed out 'each' just before the IF statement and I got this:  `Snap (Oxford handbook of clinical medicine) {
    author = "Murray Longmore";
    comments = "Add texts here...";
    isbn = 9780199609628;
    publisher = "Oxford University Press";
    title = "Oxford handbook of clinical medicine";
}
Snap (Programming Interviews Exposed: Secrets to Landing Your Next Job) {
    author = "Noah Suojanen and Eric Giguere John Mongan";
    comments = "Add texts here...";
    isbn = 9788126512744; `
    ......so on

Comment: Works! Thank you! @Dravidian